# Python TypeError: 'ZipFile' object is not callable

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
# In this part, I defined the number of epochs.
EPOCHS = 40
for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
  start = time.time()
  n = 0
  # And for each epoch, I got a batch of data from training set.
  for image_x, image_y in tf.data.Dataset.zip((trainA, trainB)):
    # And passing that batch to train_step function
    gen_g_loss, gen_f_loss, disc_x_loss, disc_y_loss = train_step(image_x, image_y)
  # I printed the losses  
  print(f"Epoch: {epoch + 1} G_g_loss: {gen_g_loss} G_f_loss: {gen_f_loss} disc_x_loss: {disc_x_loss} disc_y_loss: {disc_y_loss}")
  # Here, at that part, I am getting the source image from test set and generating target images
  test = next(iter(testA))
  generate_images(generator_g, test, epoch)
  # It will save that image in output directory
  # And then, I am printing how much time does it take to complete one epoch
  print(f"Time taken for epoch {epoch} is {time.time() - start} seconds")
```

When I type the code, It shows this error as output, how can I fix it?
Any ideas? What does it mean the zipfile object is not callable?
I even declared my zip function like this beforehand:

```
# The file will be in zip format, so we need to extract it first.
# We can use ZipFile to extract all the contents.
# We are opening that zipfile and use zip.extractall function to unzip
from zipfile import ZipFile
file_name = "apple2orange.zip"
with ZipFile(file_name,'r') as zip_op:
  zip_op.extractall()
  print('Done!')
```

I declared extracting zip operation like this above. I'm writing this code in Google Colab

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-201-87fa46721090> in <module>()
          7   for image_x, image_y in tf.data.Dataset.zip((trainA, trainB)):
          8     # And passing that batch to train_step function
    ----> 9     gen_g_loss, gen_f_loss, disc_x_loss, disc_y_loss = train_step(image_x, image_y)
         10   # I printed the losses
         11   print(f"Epoch: {epoch + 1} G_g_loss: {gen_g_loss} G_f_loss: {gen_f_loss} disc_x_loss: {disc_x_loss} disc_y_loss: {disc_y_loss}")
    
    1 frames
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
       1127   if shape is None:
       1128     shape = value.shape
    -> 1129   with ops.control_dependencies(None):
       1130     placeholder = graph_placeholder(
       1131         dtype=dtype or value.dtype, shape=shape, name=name)

TypeError: in user code:

    File "<ipython-input-162-bb429d0031b9>", line 56, in train_step  *
        generator_g_opti.apply_gradients(zip(generator_g_grad, generator_g.trainable_variables))

    TypeError: 'ZipFile' object is not callable
```

I added the tensorflow part to my code here:

```
!pip install -q git+https://github.com/tensorflow/examples.git
# I applied this command in order to use pix2pix model from tensorflow examples

# And the goal is perform mapping from A to B
# Now import some ingredients to do for the network
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import tensorflow as tf
# Here I'm importing pix2pix from tensorflow.examples. So that, I don't have to build unique model from scratch.
from tensorflow_examples.models.pix2pix import pix2pix
import time
```

Answer (score 0):

`for image_x, image_y in tf.data.Dataset.zip((trainA, trainB)):`

you got double parentheses, make it

`for image_x, image_y in tf.data.Dataset.zip(trainA, trainB):`

Comment: It didn't work when I applied this.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-238-be1b1aee62ab> in <module>()
----> 7   for image_x, image_y in tf.data.Dataset.zip(trainA, trainB):
AttributeError: 'BatchDataset' object has no attribute 'isidentifier'

Comment: maybe its something with tf.data.Dataset, 
add the code where tf is declared so we know what we're dealing with

Comment: I added the tensorflow part to my code, I used tf.data.Dataset only there, not in anywhere else before

Comment: i just noticed this 
`File "<ipython-input-162-bb429d0031b9>", line 56, in train_step  *`
        `generator_g_opti.apply_gradients(zip(generator_g_grad, generator_g.trainable_variables))`

 `TypeError: 'ZipFile' object is not callable`

the error is in the train_step function, a zipfile somewhere is being treated as a function (called basically means u have something like this zipfile(), ), maybe add the train_step func

Comment: Can you explain the last part a little bit more?

Comment: after doing a small search u can ignore that part,
here `train_step(image_x, image_y)` my best shot would be to make sure image_x and image_y give the values u expect them to, print them as a str(image_x) for example